# PKCS #11 – Deriving a Key where MSB perform encryption and LSB perform CMAC operation?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, cryptographic-hardware, pkcs11

I am using Thales HSM, a PKCS #11 Compliant device. I have an 32 byte AES key and derivation input.

I want to use AES-ECB encryption Mode to derive a 32 byte key where 16 MSB should be considered as one key, and 16 LSB should be considered as an another key. How do I achieve this?

I know that `CKM_AES_ECB_ENCRYPT_DATA` mechanism and `C_DeriveKey` PKCS #11 functions allow for derivation of keys using the result of an encryption operation as the key value. But my problem is how do I get 2 separated Keys (16 MSB and 16 LSB)?

This is very much needed for me to implement a System where 16 MSB perform Encryption operation, and 16 LSB perform CMAC operation.

### EDIT

I am adding some more inputs to my query here.

```
Derived_Key = encrypt_Aes_Ecb(Master_Aes_Key, Derivation_Input)
```

where `Master_Aes_Key` is a 32byte Key and

```
Derivation_input = Concatenate(Input1 , Input2)
```

Both `Input1` and `Input2` are 16bytes.

My understanding is, if

```
Derivation_input = Concatenate(Input1, 16B of Zeros)
```

gives 16MSB of derived Key, and if

```
Derivation_input = Concatenate(16B of Zeros, Input2)
```

gives 16LSB of derived_key. Am I correct?

### EDIT 2

Sample Input1:

```
00 00 00 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 WW XX YY ZZ
```

Sample Input2:

```
00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ww xx yy zz
```

where `WW, XX, YY, ZZ , ww, xx, yy, zz` would be keep changing always.

```
Derivation Input: Concatenate(Input1, Input2) 
Derived_Key = encrypt_Aes_Ecb(Master_Aes_Key, Derivation_Input)
```

Now How do I get 16MSB of derived_key as one key used for encryption/decryption, and 16LSB of derived_key as another key used for CMAC operation?

Answer (score 1):

OK so your problem is the following: You have a secure key and want to / can use it only for AES-ECB. You want to extend the security of this key to derived keying material which deterministically depends on some context material. Finally you need to derive a 32-byte key.

Now, one could use [NIST SP800-108 (PDF)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-108.pdf) as guidance and use the counter-based construction. Here you would take the variable parts of your input, put them into the "fixed part" and run a counter for two blocks. So you would take the 8 variable bytes as the 8 most significant bytes to the ECB input and use the lower 8 bytes as a counter. So your input would be `WW XX YY ZZ ww xx yy zz 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and `WW XX YY ZZ ww xx yy zz 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01` and the first output block could be used for the encryption and the second for the MAC of the scheme.